# Neo4j all reachable nodes thru a specific relationship from a specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to find out all reachable nodes via one specific relationship starting from a node.

I have the below graphs.

```
(User) --[LOGGED_IN]--> (Ip)
(User) --[FRIEND]--> (User)
```

I would like to find all reachable User nodes thru LOGGED_IN relationship.
eg.

```
    user1 logged_in ip1
    user2 logged_in ip1
    user2 logged_in ip2
    user3 logged_in ip2
    user3 logged_in ip3
    user4 logged_in ip3
    user5 logged_in ip4
    user1 friend user5
```

If I start from user1 I want to find user1, user2, user3, user4.
I would like to ignore the FRIEND relationship.

I know if I only have [:LOGGED_IN] relationship I can do the below cypher. But I also have FRIEND relationship and this will also give me the users linked by [:FRIEND]

```
MATCH (u:User)-[*]->(connected:User)
WHERE u.user_id = <user1_id>
RETURN connected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (with the appropriate value for `<user1_id>`):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:logged_in*0..]-(connected:User)
WHERE u.user_id = <user1_id>
RETURN DISTINCT connected;
```

The `(u:User)-[:logged_in*0..]-(connected:User)` pattern:

- requires all matched relationships to be of type `logged_in`.
- specifies a lower bound of `0` for the variable-length path pattern, which allows the `u` node itself to be assigned to `connected`.
- does not specify a direction for the `loggeded_in` relationship, to permit traversals from `Ip` nodes to `User` nodes (and vice versa).

The `DISTINCT` keyword is used to eliminate duplicate results.

This query will always return the `u` node (if it exists), since a node is trivially reachable from itself.

[UPDATED]

If you have enough data, then the variable-length path pattern will have to  specify a reasonable upper bound (e.g., `[:logged_in*0..5]`) to avoid running out of memory or having the query take forever to complete.

Comment: The problem is I have millions of nodes.... This will run too slow and sometimes even crash my neo4j. I am doing some dumb things like this. This is fast but it is not elegant and i could not find all reachable nodes. I can only find nodes in the depth I specified.
  <br/>`MATCH (u: User)-[:LOGGED_IN]->(ip1: Ip)
WITH ip1
MATCH (tier1: User)-[:LOGGED_IN]->(ip1: Ip)
WITH tier1
MATCH (tier1)-[:LOGGED_IN]->(ip2: Ip)
WITH ip2
MATCH (tier2: User)-[:LOGGED_IN]->(ip2: Ip)
RETURN ip2`

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can conveniently do the equivalent by specifying an upper bound on the variable-length path pattern. This would still not give you all reachable nodes, though.

Comment: I guess this is an exponential computation....[:logged_in*0..4] is fast that it took 7s. [:logged_in*0..6] is driving my CPU overheating...lol

Answer (score 1):

If your nodes are deeply interconnected, then cypher alone may not work out for you, since MATCH operations in cypher with variable-length paths are all about finding all possible paths that fit the pattern, and that quickly gets you into trouble with the number of possible paths goes through the roof. This isn't a good fit when you're only concerned about distinct connected nodes.

If you have access to APOC Procedures, there are some [path expander procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) that are optimized toward finding connected nodes. After installing and configuring APOC, give this a try:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.user_id = <user1_id>
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(u, {relationshipFilter:'LOGGED_IN', labelFilter:'>User', filterStartNode:true}) YIELD node as connected
RETURN connected;
```